# Powermock not able to mock static methods when using scala, junit

Tags: scala, junit, powermock

I have used Powermock previously with java and junit. I have been successfully been able to mock static methods like in the following example:

```
@PrepareForTest({ TimeHelper.class, MainApp.class })
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestSuite {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
     PowerMockito.mockStatic(TimeHelper.class);
     Mockito.doReturn("2015-01-01 00:00:00").when(TimeHelper.getUnixTime());
    }
}
```

However, the same doesn't seem to work when translated to scala. Note that the 'getUnixTime' method that we call below is also implemented in scala.

```
@PrepareForTest(Array( classOf[TimeHelper], classOf[MainApp] ))
@RunWith(classOf[PowerMockRunner])
class TestSuite {
    @Before
    def setUp() {
     PowerMockito.mockStatic(classOf[TimeHelper]);
     Mockito.doReturn("2015-01-01 00:00:00").when(TimeHelper.getUnixTime());
    }
}
```

When running the test implemented in scala, I seem to get the value returned by the test, instead of the mocked value. Can someone point out what I am missing here?

**EDIT**: Here's the signature of the getUnixTime function in scala:

```
object TimeHelper{
    def getUnixTime(): String = {
      //logic
    }
}
```

Comment: So could you show us your source of `TimeHelper.getUnixTime`? Is it implemetned in a companion object or something else?

Comment: Yes indeed it is implemented in a companion object. Added an edit with the signature..

Comment: Have a look at the byte code. Are you sure that TimeHelper.class looks like an ordinary class that PowerMock could do its bytecode-manipulation black voodoo magic on ... what I mean is: what makes you think that the final output of scalac is fully compatible with PowerMock? Beyond that: simple dont write static code that needs mocking. That is the real problem here ;-)

Comment: I see the following class files created: TimeUtils.class, TimeUtils$.class and TimeUtils$$anonfun$1.class. Not completely sure what this implies. I'll check it out. Rearding the second part, I totally agree and I am not much in favor of mocking myself. This one did need mocking, since the getUnixTime() function gives undeterministic results and I do not happen to see any other way I can test modules which make use of it. Please feel free to add any suggestions.